# Can I assign the result of a function on multiple lines? Python

Tags: python, line-breaks

Lets say I have a function that return a lot of variables:

```
def func():
   return var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e, var_f, var_g, var_h, var_i,
```

Using this function results in very long lines

```
var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e, var_f, var_g, var_h, var_i = func()
```

Ideally, I would like to use the line breaker `\`, e.g.

```
a = var \
    + var \
    + var \
    + var \
    + var
```

However, I don't think this is possible with the result of a function (i.e. unpacking tuple). Are there methods to do so? Or should I find another way to return fewer variables? Do you have any other style suggestions?

Comment: "However, I don't think this is possible" - did you **try it**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the variables in round brackets

```
(var_a,
 var_b,
 var_c,
 var_d,
 var_e,
 var_f,
 var_g,
 var_h,
 var_i) = func()
```

Comment: ah perfect! This is something I tried before, but I think without the round brackets! Great

Answer (score 3):

if you want you can accept the output of the function as a tuple

```
ans = func()
```

I don't know what exactly is this value,
but you could consider using a data class to use the returned value, making it easier to access the data

```
class data():
    def __init__(self,var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e, var_f, var_g, var_h, var_i):
        self.var_a = var_a
        self.var_b = var_b
        self.var_c = var_c
        self.var_d = var_d
        self.var_e = var_e
        self.var_f = var_f
        self.var_g = var_g
        self.var_h = var_h
        self.var_i = var_i

def func():
    return data(var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e, var_f, var_g, var_h, var_i)

a=func()
print(a.var_a)
```

Comment: Instead of a class you could also use a dict holding your result. e.g. `result['a']=var_a` With both approaches you could address the variables by name as you need them.

Comment: @Jacob you are correct, but I personally prefer data class since as I write the code I can only access the classes fields as opposed to a dictionary where I might try to access the wrong keys (especially relevant where fields names are longer than "var_a")
and for me, it is also more convenient when the IDE helps me to type the name of the fields

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Nice to see other suggestions as well. For my specific implementation, I really needed to extract it straight away

Comment: and with your first suggestion (extracting as tuple), I would still require to unpack the tuple resulting in a very long line still

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing, you can also work with multiple elements and use it to ignore some of them:

```py
*ignore, i = func() # Ignore all elements except the last one
a, *ignore = func() # Ignore all elements except the first one
a, *ignore, i = func() # Ignore all elements except the first and last one
```

Comment: ah good to know. I have done this before, but then `var,_,_,_ = other_func()`